# Как подключиться по ssh к серверу по кириллическому домену?

Tags: linux, bash, unix, shell, ssh

Пытаюсь подключиться к серверу, к которому привязан IDN домен (новавеб.рф), но bash таких манипуляций не воспринимает, кажется.

```
$ ssh root@новавеб.рф
ssh: Could not resolve hostname \320\275\320\276\320\262\320\260\320\262\320\265\320\261.\321\200\321\204: Name or service not known
```

Comment: домены под рф на самом деле достуны по другому адресу на латинице. посмотри что в браузере на самом деле отображает адрес. и попробуй по IP подключиться

Comment: текст лучше прикладывать в виде текста, а не в виде картинки. исправить вопрос можно, нажав [edit]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

например, можно воспользоваться программой *idn* (из одноимённого пакета, имеющегося во всех популярных дистрибутивах):

```
$ ssh root@$(idn новавеб.рф)
```

**или** сразу подставлять *реальное имя* домена:

```
$ ssh root@xn--80acbbp8bh.xn--p1ai
```

получив его однократно той же, к примеру, программой:

```
$ idn новавеб.рф
xn--80acbbp8bh.xn--p1ai
```

**или**, получив имя, добавить две строчки в `~/.ssh/config`:

```
host новавеб.рф
hostname xn--80acbbp8bh.xn--p1ai
```

и вызывать программу *ssh*, передавая ей исходное имя:

```
$ ssh root@новавеб.рф
```

Comment: а ещё лучше настроить ssh/config и забыть о страшных именах

Comment: ssh: Could not resolve hostname (idn \320\275\320\276\320\262\320\260\320\262\320\265\320\261.\321\200\321\204): Name or service not known
Вариант со скобками не работает(

Comment: @BorisPaschenko, вы знак доллара пропустили.

Comment: @KoVadim, да, конечно, так тоже можно. дополнил ответ.